# Transforming distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expectation

There is an economy,  populated by a large number of agents. A first order condition common to all agents, is the following:

$$E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r-R+\eta_i)]=0$$

the index $i$ indicates the individual, $\eta$ is a an exogenous random variable that each individual receives (idiosyncratic shock) it is assumed to be identically and independently distributed among them, and across time. It is also assumed that $\eta_i \sim N (0, \sigma^2)$. The variables, $\theta, r, R$ are time varying. I suppress the time subscript on them, as the problem is stationary and so can be thought as some constants/parameters. The scope, is to solve for $\theta$. Also, $r \neq R$.

$$ E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i - R)]=0  \Rightarrow $$
$$ E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i ) - \exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}R)]=0  \Rightarrow $$
$$   E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i)] - E [\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}R)]=0  \Rightarrow $$
$$  E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i)]  = E [\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}]R $$
$$  E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}r] + E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}\eta_i]  = E [\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}]R $$
$$  \log \left(E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i)]\right)  = \log \left(E [\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}]R\right) $$

I then use the following approximation: $\log E (X) = E (\log X) + \frac{Var(X)}{2}$

$$  \log \left(E[\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i)]\right)  = \log \left(E [\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}]R\right) $$
$$   E[\log (\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i))] + \frac{Var(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i))}{2} = E [\log \exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}] + \frac{Var(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i})}{2} + \log R $$

$$   E[(1-\theta)\eta_i + \log (r+\eta_i)] + \frac{Var(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i))}{2} = E [{(1-\theta)\eta_i}] + \frac{Var(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i})}{2} + \log R $$

$$   E [\log (r+\eta_i)] + \frac{Var(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i}(r+\eta_i))}{2} = \frac{Var(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta_i})}{2} + \log R $$

This is where I am not quite sure how to proceed. And please let me know whether you see something wrong so far.

Comment: A single random variable being i.i.d.? Nice...

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: @Did The IID I mentioned is across cross-sections, that is across different people. Would you like to write the full economics jargon and describe the full economic environment, for making more specific the $IID$ assumption ? I am sure that would not be of any help for the algebra.

Comment: @user1729 Can you please look at the update. Do you want more details on what exactly I did?

Comment: @user17880 Yes, exactly, more details on what you did.

Comment: @user17880 All threats of showering us with economics jargon being put aside, a single random variable being i.i.d. is a funny beast. If several random variables are involved in the question you are asking (and not in the full model, irrelevant to solve the question), please explain.

Comment: Asking a good Question is not as simple as inserting "Can anyone help me with this?" in the midst of a problem setup.  The simplest problem I can imagine being asked here is, given a *single* random variable $\eta \sim N (0, \sigma^2)$, what is the expected value $E(\exp^{(1-\theta)\eta}(r-R + \eta))$, where $\theta, r, R$ are known constants?  Simple as it would be to address that, it's not clear at this time if that's the Question.

Comment: @user1729,  I understood the point. I will delete the question then and ask a new but comprehensive one. Shall I also write the step by step derivations for what I did or this is considered pedantic here ? –

Comment: @user17880 Do not delete this one - instead just edit it into the new question. It will then be re-opened.

Comment: And by all means, please insert any step by step derivation you might have reached yourself...

Comment: @Did I have updated my question

Comment: Still many irrelevant details since the question concerns one unique random variable $\eta$, but now, at least you show what you tried.  See answer (much simpler than what you might think...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Motto: Go back to the basics...

Since $\eta_i=\sigma Z$ with $Z$ standard normal, the goal is to find $\theta$ such that $$E(Z\mathrm e^{bZ})=aE(\mathrm e^{bZ}),$$ for the parameters $a$ and $b$ defined as $$a=(R-r)/\sigma,\qquad b=(1-\theta)\sigma.$$
A basic computation anybody interested in normal random variables should master yields the...

> **Key gaussian formula**: For every parameter $c$, $\color{red}{E(\mathrm e^{cZ})=\mathrm e^{c^2/2}}.$

The differentiation of this identity with respect to $c$ (or a direct computation) yields $$E(Z\mathrm e^{cZ})=c\,\mathrm e^{c^2/2}.$$
Applying this to $c=b$, one sees that the solution to the initial problem is unique and such that $a=b$, that is, $$\theta=1-\frac{R-r}{\sigma^2}.$$

**Addendum:** (Proof of the key formula) By definition, $$E(\mathrm e^{cZ})=\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{cz}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}\mathrm dz=\mathrm e^{c^2/2}\int_\mathbb R\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-(z-c)^2/2}\mathrm dz=\mathrm e^{c^2/2}.$$

Comment: I was not aware of this formula at all. Actually my training is very limited on probability theory. Do you have any reference (book) that I can use, which includes for instance the gaussian formula and its proof ? I will much appreciate it.

Comment: See Addendum. As references, did you check WP?

Comment: what is WP ? :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions