# solving for an unknown within expections with known distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this equation to solve for $x$.

$$ E\left[ e^{xa_i}a_i\right]=c E\left[ e^{xa_i}\right] $$

where $a_i$ is a RV and it's logarithm is distributed as

$$\ln a_i \sim N (-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}, \sigma^2)$$

In the above $e^{xa_i}$ I basically mean the exponent of $(xa_i)$, so maybe you want to write it as $\exp (xa_i)$.

I tried to utilized the Gaussian formula (see the link here [Transforming distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901821/transforming-distributions) )

So, by transforming the longnormal distribution this imples that the RV $a_i$ is distributed as

$a_i \sim logN (0, \sigma^2_a)$

But since now, $a_i$ is longnormally distributed i do not think that the gaussian formula ([Transforming distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901821/transforming-distributions)) applies anymore. correct ?

Can someone suggest something, whether this equation still can be solved by hand ? I was thinking whether I should take some (Taylor) approximations up to second order, but not sure around which point.

Second, I even tried to take logs from both sides and use the following approximation $E(\ln X)=\ln E(X)-\frac{Var(\log X)}{2}$

Comment: what is $exp^{xa_{i}}$? Maybe $e^{xa_{i}}$ or $\exp\left(xa_{i}\right)$?

Comment: I mean the exponent of $(xa_i)$ so it should be the second you mentioned then. I will update my question. thx